# how to complete jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime and avoid timeout

Tags: time, jestjs

I want to set the time of my jest test. However jest complains that the test exceeds timeout.

```
  beforeEach(() => {
    jest.useFakeTimers().setSystemTime(new Date('2020-01-01'))
  })
```

error

```
  ● Test suite failed to run

    thrown: "Exceeded timeout of 5000 ms for a hook.
    Use jest.setTimeout(newTimeout) to increase the timeout value, if this is a long-running test."
```

Answer (score 1):

It will work:

```
useFakeTimers({advanceTimers: true})
```